# How to get props value of boolean type in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created one component where I am passing two props - taskName which is string and status which is boolean. I found a way to get taskName in my `App.js` but it failed in case of boolean type.

Doesn't react support boolean props ?

**TaskComponent.js**

```
export default class TaskComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        var taskStatus = this.props.status;
        if(taskStatus)
            return <h1><strike>Task: {this.props.taskName}</strike></h1>
    }
}
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TaskComponent taskName="Buy Milk" status={false} />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I am getting this error while trying to get status value.

> TaskComponent.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Comment: What does `render` return `if(! taskStatus)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are not returning anything when **status is false** (by default it will **return undefined** that's why you are getting the error), You forgot the **else condition**, you need to return something when status will be `false`.

If you don't want to `render` anything then `return null`.

write it like this:

```
render() {
    var taskStatus = this.props.status;
    if(taskStatus)
        return <h1><strike>Task: {this.props.taskName}</strike></h1>
    else return null;
}
```

Comment: Wow Quick response :) , I am waiting to accept your answer. 7 minutes...

Answer (score 1):

Return a null is the `taskStatus` is false, thats the reason you get an error since nothing is returned is the `if condition` doesn't match

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <TaskComponent taskName="Buy Milk" status={true} />
    );
  }
}

class TaskComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var taskStatus = this.props.status;
        if(taskStatus)
            return <h1><strike>Task: {this.props.taskName}</strike></h1>
        else
            return null
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```